# How Can I "CAM attack" a switch/router?

Tags: networking, ethernet, router

Does someone has any script that can "CAM attack" a switch/router, so that it will act as a HUB? Are there any tools for it in the repositories?

Comment: Why do you want to know these things?

Comment: for testing purposes. if i would be a "bad" person i would rather use firesheep, etc. but i'm not.

Comment: This kind of topic is fine as an educational question. But @Lance, please try to improve your question and show that you've done some research. If you really want to understand security, you need to try the exploits and the defenses. You must do this on your own equipment, not on systems belonging to other people, or on systems belonging to your employeer (Unless your employeer gives you permission, or want you to try vulnerability tests). Also, this question really belongs on another forum like security.stackexchange.com or ServerFault.com, since this is not really a Unix-specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application you are looking for is macof which is part of the [dsniff](http://monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/) toolkit. You'll find that [ettercap](http://ettercap.sourceforge.net/) is also quite useful when doing any sort of network auditing on a switched network.

**Warning:** I'm a firm believer that you need to understand the threat to defend against it, but you best be using these tools in your *own* lab on your *own* equipment. If that is not the case, I guarantee someone much smarter than the both of us will bring down a righteous hammer on you. Play nice!